# UnknownHostException with HTTPConnection in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-wifi

An `UnknownHostException` arises when I attempt to execute the following code...

```
String line;
String url = "http://mywebsite.com";
URL theURL = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) theURL.openConnection();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
line = rd.readLine(); 
conn.disconnect();
```

I have followed suggestions from former posts to **ensure that the Internet Permission Tag appears** properly in the manifest. I also made sure that my Android has WIFI access, and that the website I am attempting to use is correct. This usually appeared to be a popular resource on StackOverflow: http://guerrarj.hubpages.com/hub/Tips-to-solve-the-UnknownHostException-on-Android

The stack trace is...

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: the_website.com
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:512)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:300)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:259)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1018)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:512)
at com.example.privacyapp.MainActivity.scrapWeb(MainActivity.java:127)
at com.example.privacyapp.MainActivity.checkLocation(MainActivity.java:148)
at com.example.privacyapp.MainActivity$1.onLocationChanged(MainActivity.java:93)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:227)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:160)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:176)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Update:** It appeared that my WIFI connection was faulty. Without a connection, the UnknownHostException arises.

Comment: have you add the internet permission in the manifest?

Comment: Yes, I did--are you referring to something other than what I mentioned in my original post?

Comment: intenetn permistion and check you link on mobile browser it's work on mobile browser or not

Comment: Is your device connecting to the internet in general ? And as  *@PintuCorna* mentioned, are you able to open the link in the mobile browser of your device ?

Comment: When i try to test myapp.herokuapp.com, i get unknownhost aswell.. So something is wrong with that website

Comment: I should have made this clearer @blganesh101. "myapp" is a dummy name, not the real website. I'll edit this now.

Comment: try to run your url in actual browser(say firefox)..if it works then it should work in your android app

Answer (score 0):

Somtimes we have to write ip address instead of "http://mywebsite.com"; so try onece using Ip address.
check also The INTERNET permission tag is a child of the manifest tag, not the application tag.! 
and check [this once](http://guerrarj.hubpages.com/hub/Tips-to-solve-the-UnknownHostException-on-Android) hope this helpful to you